# <audio> prevent track from reload on page change

Tags: html5-audio

I have a (Drupal / but it could be another too) Website with an audio track autoplayed on frontpage. The audio element is in a block somewhere in the footer, on all pages. Trouble now is if someone navigates to another page the track will start again too. Is there a way to solve this? So if a user changes the page the track stays at the position it was.

Something like set currentTime in sessionStore. and get it from there.

```
<audio id="audioplayer" autoplay>
        <source src="<?php print base_path();?>music/TomDay-WhoWeWantToBe.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="<?php print base_path();?>music/TomDay-WhoWeWantToBe.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="<?php print base_path();?>music/TomDay-WhoWeWantToBe.wav" type="audio/wav">
        Ihr Webbrwoser unterstützt das Audio-Element nicht.
    </audio>
```

If i do some changes like this `<audio id="audioplayer" autoplay preload="auto" src="<?php print base_path();?>music/TomDay-WhoWeWantToBe.mp3">`

And use some session set and get Items like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audioplayer');
window.onbeforeunload = function () { var testx = audio.currentTime; testx = testx.toFixed(2); sessionStorage.setItem('sct', testx);}
startPoint = sessionStorage.getItem('sct'); 
document.getElementById("audioplayer").src = "<?php print base_path();?>music/TomDay-WhoWeWantToBe.mp3#t=" + startPoint + "";
```

I have a solution that kinda works BUT how can i get this without putting src= into the audiotag itselfs? So i still could have different source src files? and isnt there any simpler way to get that result maybe even better?